# Is PostGIS / PostgreSQL UK Public Sector Network (PSN) compliant?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, united-kingdom

Is PostGIS / PostgreSQL UK Public Sector Network [PSN](https://www.gov.uk/government/groups/public-services-network) compliant?

... *specifically so it can be used in a UK local government council?*

Comment: yes - many UK LAs are using it, I don't have a reference though

Comment: The Ordnance Survey now produce technical specification documents including functions for loading data into Postgres. While this does not imply PSN compliance, it does indicate the traction that Postgres/Postgis has in the UK spatial sector. There is also a company called Astun, https://astuntechnology.com/, to which I have no affiliation, who spend a lot of time convincing LAs to switch to Postgres from the ESRI stack.

Comment: @JohnBarça Yeap, seen Astun. Also noted a few LA's that are using PostGIS/PostgreSQL ... but says other people are using it, isn't an answer for the bosses and security people, they want to see actual documentation

Comment: Sure, I know how that works. Have you tried phoning the PSN and asking them? For what it is worth, we loaded OS Mastermap (and many other spatial datasets) into Postgres many years ago and have never had a single issue, either with corrupted data, security, or unexpected query results. It is hard to emphasize just how good Postgres is -- I suspect you know this, hence your question.